# Data cleaning using python2

Tags: python-2.7

In my code i need to remove `$` sign using `def` and need to convert them to `numbers` for using calculations.

```
def remove_dollar(s):
    """Removes dollar signs and spaces from s.
    Returns it as a float.
    """
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    s = sales(s)
    s.remove('$')
    return ''.join(s)
remove_dollar(sales['LastSpend'])
```

Comment: what error u are getting?

Comment: The code is not very clear. What data structure is in sales. Is it just a dictionary of prices/strings? If so, is `remove_dollar` supposed to get the string or the key to the dictionary. So `s = sales(s)` is at least questionable and  if the result is just a number, i.e. a single string without $, `''.join(s)` doesn't make sense either. Finally, you dont convert to a number. You are missing something like `return float(s)`

Comment: I suggest you make a step back, pause and ponder: What is it what you have, what do you want, and how to get there.

Comment: Hello and welcom to SO. You post a code snippet but don't explain what's your problem with it. Please edit your post to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

Replacing `$` by empty string.

```
 s = s.replace('$',"")
```

Complete function :

```
def remove_dollar(s):
    """Removes dollar signs and spaces from s.
    Returns it as a float.
    """
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    s = sales(s)
    s = s.replace('$',"")
    return s
remove_dollar(sales['LastSpend'])
```